# How to expand a velocity potential to first order in $\delta$ using Taylor Expansion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, fluid-dynamics

The velocity potential formed by adding source and sink is:

$$\phi = \frac{m}{r} - \frac{m}{(r^2 - 2z\delta + \delta^2)^{1/2}}$$

Expanding the potential to first order in $\delta$ gives:

$$\phi = \frac{m}{r} - \frac{m}{r}\left(1 + \frac{z \delta}{r^2} + O(\delta^2)\right)$$

Would someone tell me how this is achieved, please? I have tried several times and I am not near the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to use the binomial expansion, at least as far as
$$ (1+x)^a = 1 + ax + O(x^2). $$
To do so, we pull the $r^2$ out of the square root to get the $1$:
$$ \frac{m}{\sqrt{r^2-2z\delta+\delta^2}} = \frac{m}{r} \left( 1- \delta\frac{2z+\delta}{r^2} \right)^{-1/2} $$
Now, $x=\delta\frac{2z+\delta}{r^2}$ is more complicated that before, but it is $O(\delta)$, so its square will be $O(\delta^2)$ and so on. Hence we can write
$$ \frac{m}{r} \left( 1- \delta\frac{2z+\delta}{r^2} \right)^{-1/2} = \frac{m}{r} \left( 1 - \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\delta\frac{2z+\delta}{r^2} + O(\delta^2) \right) = \frac{m}{r} \left( 1 + \frac{z\delta}{r^2} + O(\delta^2) \right). $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that this makes sense.. but the lecturer most definitely said "Taylor expansion" and use "Taylor theorem" so I am a little confused. Can they both work here?

Comment: The Taylor series of $(1+x)^a$ about $x=0$ *is* the binomial expansion (the $k$th derivative at zero is $a(a-1)\dotsm (a-k+1)$, and dividing by $k!$ gives the binomial coefficient). I prefer to think of it this way because I can remember the form with the binomial coefficients and then expand finitely many brackets to get the first few terms, rather than having to do some quite messy differentiation as one would when thinking of it purely in terms of Taylor's theorem.